# Full version of Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen's lecture notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, schemes

I recently have discoverd by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291785/on-the-functorial-point-of-view-in-algebraic-geometry/4564633#4564633) Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen's unpublished lecture notes which is with respect to algebraic geometry and written in view of category theory. I think I would like to read this lecture, and so I have two questions:

1. Is there a full version of this lecture notes? In this lecture notes there are no after from chapter of cohomology.
2. Is there a English version? If no, I will read it as I translate it, but I don't understand German at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably it is best to ask the author yourself?  marc.nieper-wisskirchen(at)math.uni-augsburg.de

Comment: I see that you should find the lecturen notes on libgen.is. Scimming over the topics I think you can also use basically any other textbook. For example Görtz-Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry. http://library.lol/main/C1AFB598F0B27C01CFF72F6C5C2FADBD

Comment: @Cornman From what I understand, the notes in question are of interest because they develop algebraic geometry from _the functorial point of view_, in contrast to “basically any other textbook”.

Comment: I will see Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen today, because I attend a workshop in Augsburg. I can ask! :)

Comment: Görtz Wedhorn is a very good choice though, because it has many arguments and statements which are categorical, and thus independent of the implementation of schemes!

Comment: Thank you for all comments.
@Nico Is that true? If possible, I would like to know the answer to this question. 
 I agree that Jendrik Stelzner says. I think we can almost completely develop algebraic geometry(or even if arithmetic geometry) from the functorial point of view, but unfortunately it seems that there is almost not textbooks do it.